# How to use a gnu command in c#

Tags: cmd, dos, gnu

I have a problem using a porting of the Gnu "find" in my c# app. Let me explain better:

in my winform application i have a button. When i press this button i need to launch this command (in cmd.exe this works well):

```
gfind training_set\positives\*.jpg -exec identify -format "%i 1 0 0 %w %h \n" {} ; > training_set\positives.dat
```

I used this:

```
string find = "gfind.exe ";
string command = textBox4.Text + "\\positives\\*.jpg -exec identify -format \" %i 1 0 0 %w %h \n\" {} /; > " + textBox4.Text + "\\positives.dat";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C "+find + command);
```

but the shell opens and tell me that i haven't passed any argument to the -exec

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
this work:
    string path = textBox4.Text + @"\positives\";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C cd " + textBox4.Text + " && gfind positives\*.png -exec identify -format ; > " + textBox4.Text + "\positives.dat");

BUT
-format requires this argument: '%i 1 0 0 %w %h \n' {}
in this way don't work...

**EDIT2:**
OK almost done..

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C cd " + textBox4.Text + " && gfind positives\\*.png -exec identify -format \"%i 1 0 0 %w %h\" {} ; > " + textBox4.Text + "\\positives.dat");
```

Ok this work, but print every entry in the same row:

```
positives\3LiIIH8.png 1 0 0 28 20positives\5NoLpfy.png 1 0 0 28 20positives\7XNpLX0.png 1 0 0 28 20
```

I need one entry per row like:

```
positives\3LiIIH8.png 1 0 0 28 20
positives\5NoLpfy.png 1 0 0 28 20
positives\7XNpLX0.png 1 0 0 28 20
```

\n break the sintax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved... quotes and escapes characters make me crazy

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "/C cd " + textBox4.Text + " && gfind positives\\*.png -exec identify -format \"%i 1 0 0 %w %h\\n\" {} ; > " + textBox4.Text + "\\positives.dat");
```